# Creating a windows folder from Sharepoint form column value

Tags: folder, network-drive

I am not sure if this is possible in sharepoint 2013. But just wanted to see if any one has any thoughts on it. So I have a basic project request tool and when ever a user puts in a request a unique RequestID is generated. Now, my question is that is there a way that I can create a folder automatically in a windows drive location with request ID as my folder name. This windows drive is on a network where we keep our team docs and other team related stuff.

Thanks

Comment: How SharePoint Online is involved in the whole process?

Comment: Consider the option of Document library instead of folder file system. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Your options will vary according to the solution design

**Project Request Tool as a Provider-Hosted add-in**

If you are using a Provider-Hosted add-in and your remote web is hosted in on-premises server, then you just need to add API action to call folder creation operation.

**Project Request Tool as a SharePoint-Hosted-Hosted add-in or SPFx Solution**

If you have a SharePoint-Hosted add-in, create a custom Web API in your server and create a action to create folders in a given network path.

Then call that API action from your project request tool.

**Project Request Tool as a Out of the Box list/library**

If you use a out of the box list for project request tool, then use a remote event receiver to call your custom API.

Whatever the solution you accomodate, you need to consider following factors

- Cross-Domain access
- User authentication
- Security implication of the entire solution

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. i will look into it and will update you guys., Thank you very much for the help.